# ¿Pasa algo con las imágenes o el problema es mío?

Tags: bug, estado-completado

Hace un rato vi una pregunta de otro sin la imagen, se veía el cuadro con el signo de `?` dentro, ya saben cuál es, el de *missed image*.

Ahora estaba revisando [una respuesta mía que tenía imágenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967), y no se ven:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acabo de añadir una imagen en esta pregunta de cómo se ve... y tampoco me aparece la imagen.

**¿Es algún problema temporal?**  **¿Se ha informado de esta falla en alguna parte?**

Es la primera vez que veo que esto ocurre.

Comment: Puedo ver las imágenes en la pregunta enlazada. ¿Siguen sin verse?

Comment: yo tambien las veo.. sera algo de tu servidor?

Comment: Existe un reporte en [so]: [Is i.stack.imgur.com down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372187/is-i-stack-imgur-com-down). Al parecer no estás solo en esto ;)

Comment: Y otro en [meta.se]: [Failed to upload an image, “An error occurred at imgur”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313725/failed-to-upload-an-image-an-error-occurred-at-imgur)

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta que los enlaces no son de problemas con las imágenes en si, pero al momento de subirlas. Los dejaré aquí en caso de que estén relacionados.

Comment: Ahora sí se ven. Antes no se veían, como muestra la imagen adjunta más arriba, la cual tampoco se veía cuando escribí la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano ayer experimente lo mismo, incluso en imágenes que tenía en Github, la razón es que son urls de "imgur" que fueron creadas en el sitio SOes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema estaba relacionado con [https://imgur.com/](http://%20https://imgur.com/) que usamos como servicio para subir imágenes, no se mostraban y tampoco se podían subir.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372187/is-i-stack-imgur-com-down

Incluso en mi cuenta de `github` tengo imágenes las cuales tampoco se mostraban.